# Github desktop caches deleted local repository

Tags: github

I'm new at GitHub and I'm having this issue: I created three private repositories for my project, all fine. On the fourth one, for some reason GitHub desktop included the node_modules folder (its an angular cli app), so I deleted the repository from GitHub.com and from GitHub desktop. When I try to recreate it, it is "cached" on my Mac, even if I copy everything to another folder, and it tries to upload the node_module files.

I also changed the name of the repository, copied all the files but node_modules folder to another folder. Same happens over and over.

I couldn't find anything on internet about this. Sorry if its a newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could try to delete the git folder that it's being hidden by default.
   Go to in file explore -Views- select "Hidden Items" and try to remove the git folder from here. After that set up your .gitignore file and pass node_modules before you use `git init` [image]
2. Use this in your terminal, if you are using VS Code use this in the same folder you are having the problem : `git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt know a hidden folder was created. I deleted the .git folder and everything worked perfectly. Thanks so much!